# Getting Theme information from the style.css file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

With a Wordpress theme, it is necessary to add information to the top of the style.css file:

e.g; for the default theme there is this:

```
/*
Theme Name: WordPress Default
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The default WordPress theme based on the famous <a href="http://binarybonsai.com/kubrick/">Kubrick</a>.
Version: 1.6
Author: Michael Heilemann
Author URI: http://binarybonsai.com/
Tags: blue, custom header, fixed width, two columns, widgets
*/
```

Are there any wordpress functions to get this information programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get_theme_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_data)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `get_theme_data()` or this PHP script I put together quickly:

```
<?php
$file = file('your file location');
$contents = '';
foreach($file as $lines => $line){
$contents .= $line;
}
preg_match('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', $contents, $themeinfo);
echo nl2br($themeinfo[0]);
?>
```

Comment: How to read external style.css info without Wordpress function?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `get_theme_data` function was deprecated in WP 3.4 and replaced with `wp_get_theme`. The replacement function does not retrieve all of the same elements from `styles.css` as `get_theme_data` did, specifically the `ThemeURI` element now returns the theme’s directory, not the value of `Theme URL`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme